# Contact form email sends, but the message is in the subject

Tags: php, email

My contact form on my web page finally send emails, but it doesn't send it in the proper format. This is the email of what I am getting. I've hidden the email and organization for privacy reasons.

```
From-- norgun
Subject-- Test  Email: ***@gmail.com  Message: Sbsbdb
Message-- 
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
From: Test <***@gmail.com>
Reply-To: <***@gmail.com>
X-Mailer: PHP/7.0.21
```

Anyway, as you can see from the above, the name, email, and message content that the person would've written in the contact form are in the subject line instead of the actual email box. Is there a way that I could format my code so that the message and the name that they wrote down are in the message box instead of the subject box, and the email gets sent from the person who put their email in the form, not "norgun" which is what I came up with for the website?

Here is my code so far:

```
<?php
$to = 'index@indexmarkets.biz';
$name = !empty($_POST['name']) ? filter_var(trim($_POST['name']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : '';
$from = !empty($_POST['email']) ? filter_var(trim($_POST['email']), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL) : $to;
$message = !empty($_POST['message']) ? filter_var(trim($_POST['message']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : '';

$body = "Name: {$name}\r\nEmail: {$from}\r\nMessage: {$message}";

$body = wordwrap($body, 70, "\r\n");

$headers = [
    'MIME-Version: 1.0',
    'Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1',
    "From: $name <$from>",
    "Reply-To: <$from>",
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' .phpversion()
];

$success = mail($to, $body, implode("\r\n", $headers));

if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest') {
    die(json_encode(['success' => $success]));
}

echo $success ? 'Sent Successfully.' : 'An error occurred';

ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: The answer you have received is correct. You would have identified this error quickly if you have checked [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). Please note that questions here should show a little research effort (see **[ask]**). Questions about code that isn't working should contain a [mcve] (which means, in a question about broken PHP code, you should not post HTML, JavaScript, and CSS that could not possibly be causing the problem).

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here, and I speak a second language so my grammar isn't so good. I'll make sure to do this in the future. However, the answer that I received didn't work, and I've done more research in this that you might think. I wouldn't have spent the time to ask this question if I didn't think that I had done everything that I could. The reason I put the other codes in there is exactly why the answer I've received doesn't work. It was because my HTML showed that I don't have a subject line for the page-viewer to fill out, and that might affect some answers.

Comment: You say, "[T]he answer that I received didn't work." How didn't it work? It is certainly the solution to the problem you're having with the body appearing in the subject. Also, by the way: your use of `implode()` makes no sense in this context. There's no reason to use it at all.

Comment: Please don't edit your question in a way that invalidates the help others have tried to give you. If your code changes that significantly, you need to ask a new question.

Comment: Okay, you're right. I can tell you don't like me that much. So, I'm going to start off by apologizing for everything that I've done, and that I'm just redirecting my frustration to you rather than at the code that I've been working so hard on. I've tried your suggestion of removing the implode, but this time I get an error from javascript. I've tried the addition of $subject, and now I don't even get an email. I've been pulling my hair over this, and I'm sorry for being such an ass.

Comment: I edited my question for a commenter below if that's okay...

Comment: First of all, this has nothing to do with whether I like you. It's about whether or not your question meets the site's quality standards. Second, I literally just told you not to radically change your question so that it invalidates existing efforts to help you. But then you did it again, anyway. The solution to your original problem as posted has already been provided: you used the wrong parameters to `mail()`. **If you want to ask a follow-up question, ask a new question. Do not radically change the question again.**

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're passing your variable `$body` as the `subject` parameter to the [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function.  This line:

```
$success = mail($to, $body, implode("\r\n", $headers));
```

Should instead be something like this:

```
$success = mail($to, $subject, $body, implode("\r\n", $headers));
```

Make sure you set `$subject` to something.

Comment: I did what you told me to do, and this time I didn't even get an email. I don't want to have the website-viewer to have to fill out a subject line, so is there a way to do this, and still get it so that the name and message are in the emails main message box?

Comment: @Nora Just set `$subject` to a value of your choosing. No one said the website-viewer had to fill it out.

Comment: Thanks--I did this, and I edited my question to show exactly what I entered. This time when I fill out the form, I am not even getting an email.

Comment: Where did you edit your question for this? I just refreshed it, and it still shows that you're sending the `$body` variable as the `subject` parameter.

Comment: @an admin removed it, and I can't edit it anymore.

Comment: @NickCoons I added $subject = !empty($_POST['subject']) ? filter_var(trim($_POST['subject']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : '';

Comment: That's a good first step, but you didn't change the line that I said needed to be changed in my initial answer. You still have `$success = mail($to, $body, implode("\r\n", $headers));`, and that one is the problem.